# Text should not be displayed behind the button VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, textbox

I am designing a search text box, with close button at the end(will be shown when TextLength > 0).
But when entering lengthy text, the close button hide the last part of text. I need to restrict the text to not cross the close button.

Note: I dont wont to restrict the MaxLength of characters, but the max length of characters to be displayed inside the textbox.

Comment: Thanks goths. Your answer really helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the close button is overlapping the search text box.

If you are using MFC, then you can use CEdit::SetRect to set the formatting rectangle of edit text. If not MFC, then use EM_SETRECT message to do the same.

I have done similar stuff in my article here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15043/iTunes-like-Find-Edit-Control